How to implement interface with input signals in Angular?
Before angular v17 I implemented my components like that:
export interface IEdit {
  editIcon?: string;
  editLink: string;
}
 
export class EditComponent implements IEdit {
  @Input({ required: true }) editIcon?: string;
  @Input() editLink: string;
}

Now my approach is:
...

export class EditComponent {
  editIcon = input.required<IEdit['editIcon']>();
  editLink = input<IEdit['editLink']>();
}

As you see, "implements" keyword are dissapeared. If something have to be added into the interface, typescript tells us no error.
Can you offer best approach to use new input signal feature and still implement interfaces? My project have a reason to have interfaces without InputSignals.
Perhaps, I can use some casting type like this?
interface ToSignal<T> = {
  [key: string]: InputSignal<T[key]>
}

export class EditComponent implements ToSignal<IEdit> {
  ...
}


EDIT:
My solution:
type ToSignal<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: InputSignal<T[K]>;
};

export class EditComponent implements ToSignal<IEdit> {
  editIcon = input.required<string>();
  editLink = input<string>();
}


Define the interface, with the type as below, since one input is not mandatory, it can have string | undefined.
export interface IEdit {
  editIcon: InputSignal<string>;
  editLink: InputSignal<string | undefined>;
}

You should set the type that the signal is using, the right hand side part requires the type to be defined, so that the signal function knows the type it handles.
...
export class App implements IEdit {
  editIcon = input.required<string>();
  editLink = input<string | undefined>();
}

Stackblitz Demo
